# Best way to detect if vec3 is between vec3(x) and vec3(y) in glsl

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, fragment-shader

As titled

I am sampling from a texture and if the color is somehow gray [vec3(.8), vec3(.9)] and an uniform is 1 I need to substitute that color with another one

I am not a glsl veteran but I am pretty sure there is a more elegant and compact (without mentioning faster) way than this:

```
vec3 textureColor = texture(texture0, oUV);

if(settings.w == 1 && textureColor.r > .8 && textureColor.r < .9
                    && textureColor.g > .8 && textureColor.g < .9
                    && textureColor.b > .8 && textureColor.b < .9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
vec3 delta = abs(textureColor - vec3(0.85, 0.85, 0.85)); // Get delta from middle vec3

if (delta.r <= 0.05) && (delta.g <= 0.05) && (delta.b <= 0.05)
```

Performance needs to be profiled, but it's sure shorter to write

Comment: Sounds nice, +1, lets give just sometime to see if someone shows up with a better one, otherwise I will accept your :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbuilt GLSL lessThan() and greaterThan() functions (supported in all GLSL versions). These give two boolean vectors as a result.

https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/greaterThan.xhtml
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/lessThan.xhtml

Then, you can use 'equal' (https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/equal.xhtml) on those results.

I would still do the first version though, even if its a bit more code, its perfectly understandable. :)

Comment: I toke the other one since I like it more, anyway thanks for your suggest, +1